# Running a macro to be executed in that workbook from a macro stored in Word

Tags: vba, excel

Hi have a macro (lets call it Macro A) in a Word document that I want to do the following:

1. Open an existing macro-enabled workbook that has a macro in it (Macro B)
2. Run Macro B.
3. Close and save the macro-enable workbook as a .xls.

I've managed to get everything working except part 2 - Running the macro. Please help!!!

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub Monthly_Commission_Extract()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim strFileName As String
Dim SaveAs As String
strFileName = "\\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Hiport Admin\Month End\Monthly Commission       Extract\MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER"
SaveAs1 = "\\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Hiport Admin\Month End\Monthly Commission Extract\2nd Save"

Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Workbooks.Open FileName:="\\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Hiport Admin\Month End\Monthly    Commission Extract\MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER.xlsm"
oExcel.Visible = True

Application.Run "MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER.xls!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data()"

ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveAs1, xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close
DoEvents


Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "HELP ME"

End Sub
```

The code is failing at this line:

```
Application.Run "MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER.xls!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
oExcel.Run "'MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER.xlsm'!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data"
```

Or better yet, use `Set` like this:

```
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Hiport Admin\Month End\Monthly    Commission Extract\MONTHLY COMMISSION MASTER.xlsm")
oExcel.Visible = True

oExcel.Run "'" & oWB.Name & "'!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data"
```

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "'" & oWB.Name & "'!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data"

Comment: @Andrew, sorry, my mistake, this one should work: `oExcel.Run "'" & oWB.Name & "'!Retrieve_Monthly_Commission_Data"`